# How to measure this component

Tags: pcb-design, components

I want to know how to measure this components in the attached picture. If I'm right they are beads. The second one the brown one I thought at first that it is a capacitor but I can't measure its capacitance so I think it is a bead too.
[image]
How to measure their values and what are they called?

Comment: Very similar to this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/438624/identify-unknown-capacitor-and-resistor-values/438627?noredirect=1#comment1096896_438627

Comment: No.these are not capacitors.i know how to measure capacitors.i actually measured all the capacitors on this board by desoldering them and measuring them.but those are not capacitors

Comment: How did you measure these components? With a multimeter or RCL meter? And how did you dind out those were not capacitors? Next, is there any silkscreen (white) text next to the components?

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried to do so far in the question. If people don't know whether you've tried only to test these in circuit they're going to make sure you're not trying to test them in circuit.

Comment: They could be capacitors, despite your measurements.  If they are very small values, your meter may not be capable measuring them.  If they are inductors, you could use an ohmmeter - an inductor of that size should look like a short circuit to an ohmmeter.  But, I expect they are capacitors.  Most inductors are dark gray, not yellow or tan or brown

Comment: I measured them using a multimeter.i think the problem is they are smaller than the range of my multimeter (my meter ranges from 20nF to 200uF) .i took them of circuit and tried measuring them.the other ones measures just fine.should i buy LCR meter or a multimeter with a lower range to measure them

Comment: I have this : https://www.deree.com.tw/de-5000-lcr-meter.html

Answer (score 4):

The first one has designator L1 so it most likely is a ferrite bead.

The second one is most likely a capacitor. You can't measure capacitors when they are connected to the circuit, the rest of the circuitry will affect the reading. The capacitor value might be so low that general purpose multimeter cannot measure it.

Comment: OP also claimed that items marked red are not capacitors. Possibility is that OP measured all components the OP recognized as capacitors, like electrolytics and tantalums, and did not measure components not recognized as capacitors by OP.

Comment: Think you're right

Comment: I took them off circuit because in circuit will measure all parallel capacitors value.i think i should use a LCR meter to measure them since i used a general purpose multimeter.how to measure the first one the ferrite bead ? Or is their a particular inpedence for them judged by size

Comment: Ferrite beads have a rated impedance at 100MHz usually. In addition to DC resistance, and maximum current they can handle.

Comment: So how would i find a replacement ferrite bead for this one i have ? How would i measure it's value to find the correct one.